# Do you know Atom one light color scheme for vim

Tags: vim, atom-editor

I'm looking for One light syntax highlight for vim.
I found `atom-dark` syntax highlighting file, but I cannot find `One light`.

Do you know One light for vim or similar color scheme?

Comment: Google knows a lot more about such things than random strangers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a color scheme called [one-light](https://github.com/lloeki/vim-one-colorschemes/tree/master/colors). Is that it?